# Find order of $X_{2n} := \langle x,y|x^n = y^2 = 1, xy = yx^2 \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Let $n$ be a multiple of $3$, i.e. $n = 3k, k \geq 1$ and consider the group
$$X_{2n} := \langle x,y|x^n = y^2 = 1, xy = yx^2 \rangle $$

Show that $|X_{2n}| = 6$.

(Source problem: dummit and foote, abstract algebra, p28 exercise 17)

**Attempt**: I managed to show that $|X_{2n}|\leq 6$ because I already have derived that $x^3 = 1$ and the commutation relation tells us that we can write every element in the form $y^i x^j$ with $0 \leq i \leq 1, 0 \leq j \leq 2$ so we have $6 = 2.3$ elements at most.

Now, $D_6$ is a group that satisfies the same relations as we have in $X_{2n}$, thus we must also have $|X_{2n}| \geq 6$. I'm unsure how I can formally justify the last step. Maybe make some embedding from the dihedral group in the given group?

Any input will be appreciated!

Note: I know what a homomorphism is, but at this point the book didn't introduce it (formally or unformally), nor did the book introduce presentations and free groups formally.

Comment: The free group on two letters $\langle x,y\rangle$ maps *onto* the dihedral group of order 6, which can be described by $\langle r,s | r^3 = 1, s^2 = 1, s^{-1}rs = r^{-1} = r^2\rangle$, using $x \mapsto r$ and $y \mapsto s$. Since $r^n=1$ and $rs = sr^2$, the homomorphism from $\langle x,y\rangle$ onto that dihedral group  induces a homomorphism from $X_{2n}$ onto the dihedral group, so $|X_{2n}|$ is divisible by $6$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The book has not introduced homomorphisms at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group with given presentation is the largest group on the given generators satisfying the given relations.

Since you have proved $\vert X_{2n}\vert\le6$, we just need a group of order six with the same presentation.

$D_6$ is such a group:  because once we know $x^3=e$, then $xy=yx^2\iff xy=yx^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood the question correctly.

Comment: I wrote $D$ instead of $X$.  It is pretty easy to check that none of those $6$ are equal.

Comment: If it is pretty easy, could you please explain why $x \neq 1?$

Comment: No? The relation $x^2=1$ does not necessarily imply that $x\neq 1$.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta you're both right.

Answer (score 0):

Hints for the solution are given [here](http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/~zabrocki/math6120/index2.html):

Section 1.2 Exercise 17. Let $X_{2n}= < x,y | x^n = y^2 = 1, xy=yx^2 >$.

(a) Show that if $n=3k$ then $X_{2n}$ has order 6, and it has the same generators and relations as $D_6$ when $x$ is replaced by $r$ and $y$ by $s$.

(b) Show that if $gcd(3,n) = 1$ then $x$ satisfies the additional relation 
$x=1$.  In this case deduce that $X_{2n}$ has order $2$. Use facts that $x^n =1$ and $x^3 = 1$.